# How to identify one polygon from a multipolygon in Mapbox?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am plotting a multipolygon in mapbox, that means even though the polygons are visibly separate but they are linked to the same source. If I add a click handler to this, and then click on any one of the polygons from the multipolygon, it effects all other polygons in the multipolygon equally.

Now my problem is, that I want to identify which specific polygon was clicked from the multipolygons.

Suppose I call a function when someone clicks on the source/layer, I want to send a unique identifier which denotes which polygon was clicked from among the multipolygons.

How can I achieve this?

Below is snippet of code that might be relevant:

```js
for (let k = 0; k < sectionResult.data.response.length; k++) {
  let features = sectionResult.data.response[k].coordinates.map((item) => {
    return {
      type: 'Feature',
      geometry: {
        type: 'Polygon',
        coordinates: item
      }
    };
  });
  map.addSource(sectionResult.data.response[k].name, {
    type: 'geojson',
    data: {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: features
    }
  });
  map.addLayer({
    id: sectionResult.data.response[k].name,
    type: 'fill',
    source: sectionResult.data.response[k].name,
    paint: {
      'fill-color': '#00e',
      'fill-opacity': 0.3
    }
  });
  map.addLayer({
    id: `${sectionResult.data.response[k].name}-labels`,
    type: 'symbol',
    source: sectionResult.data.response[k].name,
    layout: {
      'text-field': sectionResult.data.response[k].name,
      'text-size': 20
    },
    paint: {
      'text-color': '#fff308'
    }
  });
  map.addLayer({
    id: `${sectionResult.data.response[k].name}-borders`,
    type: 'line',
    source: sectionResult.data.response[k].name,
    layout: {},
    paint: {
      'line-color': '#fff308',
      'line-width': 3
    }
  });
  map.on('mousemove', sectionResult.data.response[k].name, function (e) {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
    let mapLayer = map.getLayer(
      `${sectionResult.data.response[k].name}-borders-onHover`
    );
    if (typeof mapLayer === 'undefined') {
      map.addLayer({
        id: `${sectionResult.data.response[k].name}-borders-onHover`,
        type: 'line',
        source: sectionResult.data.response[k].name,
        layout: {},
        paint: {
          'line-color': '#fff308',
          'line-width': 3
        }
      });
    }
  });
  map.on('mouseleave', sectionResult.data.response[k].name, function (e) {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
    let mapLayer = map.getLayer(
      `${sectionResult.data.response[k].name}-borders-onHover`
    );
    if (typeof mapLayer !== 'undefined') {
      map.removeLayer(`${sectionResult.data.response[k].name}-borders-onHover`);
    }
  });
  map.on('click', sectionResult.data.response[k].name, function (e) {
    functionCall(); //I want to pass the unique identifier of the polygon that was clicked.
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [queryRenderedFeatures](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#queryrenderedfeatures) this will return the features in a concrete filter, including the mouse position.

```
        map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
        var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point);

        // Limit the number of properties we're displaying for
        // legibility and performance
        var displayProperties = [
            'type',
            'properties',
            'id',
            'layer',
            'source',
            'sourceLayer',
            'state'
        ];

        var displayFeatures = features.map(function (feat) {
            var displayFeat = {};
            displayProperties.forEach(function (prop) {
                displayFeat[prop] = feat[prop];
            });
            return displayFeat;
        });

        document.getElementById('features').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
            displayFeatures,
            null,
            2
        );
    });
```

You have a full example [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/)